# Can't find the NullPointerException Error

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to build a Snake Game, where the snake is eating square orbs.

Before, the program was running perfectly, but when I ran it a couple of days ago, it yelled at me for something about a `NullPointerException`. I tried looking for what caused it, and it was in my `Snake` class.

Here is the code for the main class:

```
Snake s;
Score score;
//Menu m;
int sc1 = 20;

PVector food;

void setup() {
  size(700, 700);
  //m = new menu;
  //m.show();
  s = new Snake();
  score = new Score();
  //m.startGame();

  frameRate(10);
}

void pickLocation() {
  int cols = width/sc1;
  int rows = height/sc1;
  food = new PVector(floor(random(cols-20)), floor(random(rows-20)));
  food.mult(sc1);
}

void draw() {
  background(51);
  if (s.eat(food)) {
     pickLocation();
     score.addPoints(10);
  }
  pickLocation();

  score.show();
  s.update();
  s.show();
  s.death();
  if (s.dead == true) {
    score.highScores();
  }

  if (score.totalScore != s.i/10) {
    score.totalScore = s.i * 10;
  }

  if (s.dead && score.totalScore < score.highScore) {
    score.totalScore = 0;
  }

  fill(255, 0, 100);
  rect(food.x, food.y, sc1, sc1);
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode == UP) {
    s.dir(0, -1);
  } else if (keyCode == DOWN) {
    s.dir(0, 1);
  } else if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
    s.dir(1, 0);
  } else if (keyCode == LEFT) {
    s.dir(-1, 0);
  }
}
```

The menu I commented out right now.

The `Score` class:

```
class Score {
  int totalScore = 0; //will add the total score to the 
  int highScore; //will hold the user's high score in it.
  int tempScore; //will hold the user's score after the snake dies.

  Score() {
  }

  //this method is used when the snake eats the
  //food. Eating the food will give 10 points to it.
  void addPoints(int x) {
    totalScore = totalScore + x;
  }

  //this method will calculate to see if the user
  //has a new high score, only if the snake has
  //officially died.
  void highScores() {
    if (totalScore > highScore) {
      text("new highscore!", height/2, width/2);
      highScore = totalScore;
      totalScore = 0;
    }
  }

  void show() {
    text("Score: " + totalScore, 20, 20);
    text("High Score: " + highScore, 20, 40);
  }
}
```

And finally, my `Snake` class, where the problem is located at:

```
class Snake {
  float x, y;
  float xSpeed = 1;
  float ySpeed = 0;
  int total = 0;
  ArrayList<PVector> tail = new ArrayList<PVector>();
  boolean dead = false;
  int i = 0;

  Snake() {
  }

  boolean eat (PVector pos) {
    float d = dist(x, y, pos.x, pos.y);
    if (d < 1) {
      total++;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  void dir(float x, float y) {
    xSpeed = x;
    ySpeed = y;
  }

  void death() {
    for (i = 0; i < tail.size(); i++) {
      PVector pos = tail.get(i);
      float d = dist(x, y, pos.x, pos.y);
      if (d < 1) {
        println("starting over");
        total = 0;
        tail.clear();
        dead = true;
      } else {
        dead = false;
      }
    }
  }

  void update() {
    if (total > 0) {
      if (total == tail.size() && !tail.isEmpty()) {
        tail.remove(0);
      }
      tail.add(new PVector(x, y));
    }

    x = x + xSpeed * sc1;
    y = y + ySpeed * sc1;

    x = constrain(x, 0, width-sc1);
    y = constrain(y, 0, height-sc1);
  }

  void show() {
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    for (PVector v : tail) {
      rect(v.x, v.y, sc1, sc1);
    }
    rect(x, y, sc1, sc1);
    //rect(x, y, w, h);
  }
}
```

My question is, is there something who can recognize the error and what should I do to fix such an error, please.

Comment: What line is throwing the error? Can you link the stack trace?

Comment: It was line 14 that was throwing the error.

Comment: Line 14 in the snake class?

Comment: That is where it kept bringing me to.

Comment: this line here? `float d = dist(x, y, pos.x, pos.y);`

Just making sure it's the same for me as it is for you.

Comment: That is the exact line.

Comment: So does it happen when you compile or when you try to eat a pellet? Also can you link your dist() function?

Comment: It happens when I compile the program and it won't run, but will show me a gray screen which will eventually say not responding beside the running sketch, it doesn't happen when the snake tries to eat a pellet.

Comment: I'm not seeing a definition for your dist() function. Can you link it please?

Comment: Also, the program uses dist() to determine the distance between two points as said in the Processing Reference page for dist() (https://processing.org/reference/dist_.html). It returns a value that is used by the 'float d'

Comment: try    `float d = dist(&x, &y, pos.x, pos.y);` If you only plan on using one snake you can make them static as well and that could save future headaches.

Comment: Okay, I tried that, and now it is giving me a bunch of errors, the errors are the following: syntax error on(s), misplaced constructs, missing a right parenthesis, syntax error on "&", delete this, error on ".", missing a left parenthesis, it apparently thinks y is a function and is saying that the variable "d" does not exist, even though it **is** there.

Comment: What language are you using? &x should be a pointer to x unless this isn't C++?

Comment: this is not C++, this is Processing.

Comment: Never heard of it. I assumed processing was some sort of API. Look up syntax for pointers in processing and use that to make pointers to X and Y. That might solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, at least.

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace please?

Comment: Here is the stacktrace: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at SnakeGame$Snake.eat(SnakeGame.java:182)
 at SnakeGame.draw(SnakeGame.java:44)
 at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2426)
 at processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT$12.callDraw(PSurfaceAWT.java:1557)
 at 
 processing.core.PSurfaceNone$AnimationThread.run(PSurfaceNone.java:316)

Comment: Please make log file of values passing to **dist** function. Then you can check which value is wrong. Format could be CSV.

Comment: Please link between crossposts. This question has also been asked [here](https://discourse.processing.org/t/cant-find-nullpointerexception/778).

Comment: @Ananth, here is the log file for you:x is 0 and y is 0, and pos is null.

Comment: @JordanGreen There is calculation in **dist** function so before execute **processing** validates values if null then show NullPointerException error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get into the habit of [debugging your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) to understand exactly what's going on. You know that this line is throwing the NPE:

```
float d = dist(x, y, pos.x, pos.y);
```

So next, you need to understand the values of every variable on that line. You could just print them out:

```
boolean eat (PVector pos) {
  println("x: " + x);
  println("y: " + y);
  println("pos: " + pos);
  float d = dist(x, y, pos.x, pos.y);
```

If you do this, you'll see this output:

```
x: 0.0
y: 0.0
pos: null
```

This tells you that your `pos` variable is `null`, which is what's causing your `NullPointerException`.

Now you can trace backwards through your code to understand why the `eat()` function is being given a `null` argument.

In the future, please narrow your problem down to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of posting your whole program.

Comment: And on top of that @Kevin Workman, I did do some debugging to answer a comment that someone asked me for, and on top of that, I did do some debugging, like you asked me to do and I believe that it has something to do with how the function 'eat' is being executed. Now I could be wrong on it, but that's where I think the problem is being set to.

Comment: @JordanGreen Right, you want to look at how you're calling the `eat()` function. What value are you passing into it? Why is that variable `null`? When are you setting that variable? Are you sure the value is set before you call `eat()`? Hint: it's not.

Comment: When I call on the `eat` function, the parameter being passed is `food`, which is a `PVector` and that is being passed because it is the parameter it needs to do its job. Since `food.x` and `food.y` are both zero, the parameter is assumed to be null, that is why I am getting a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @JordanGreen That's not quite right. A `PVector` of `0,0` is not `null`. It's `null` because you haven't set it to a value when you're using it. When do you set its value? Is that happening before or after you're trying to use it? Trace through your code line by line to understand exactly what it's doing.

Comment: I don't see where I gave the variables in the `SnakeGame` class. I definitely know it won't be in the `Menu` or `Score` classes. Could it be in the `Snake` class?

Comment: @JordanGreen Where do you set the `food` variable? Is that happening before or after you're using it?

Comment: `food` is declared in the `SnakeGame` class at line 8, which I believe it is happening before the `eat` function is being called on to do its job.

Comment: When `s.eat` is called is called on, `pickLocation()` is giving the `food` variable its values which is `food = new PVector(floor(random(cols-20)), floor(random(rows-20)));`

Comment: @JordanGreen I don't think that's the right order. Try adding print statements before each of those lines to see which one comes first.

Comment: When printing it out, it is telling me that x is 0 and y is also 0 as well.

Comment: @JordanGreen Right, but what about the `pos` variable? That's the thing that's `null`. You aren't setting that before you use it. The only place that sets it is called **after** you use it.